# Transferring Touch points between classes [Objective-C]

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on an alternate version of a program I already wrote, it's mostly for the sake of understanding a little more.

In x-Code (Objective-C), I have a ViewController that calls out a UIView (GraphicsView) that draws a line from the center to the touch point. This sub-view is smaller than the larger ViewController. 
The view controller has a label that outputs the coordinates of the touched point.

So far I was able to get everything working, so that if you touch inside the sub-view you get the line AND the coordinates updated and if you touch outside the sub-view you only get the coordinates updated. I did this using delegates which was a little complicated.

I've been reading some books and I learned about using the extern feature and global variables (which are supposed to be bad practice) and I wanted to try the same app but using global variables.

I declared my externCGPoint in the ViewController.h and imported it on the GraphicsView.m file and in the method touches began I put the definition of myGlobalPoint = touchedpoint; followed by an NSLog that displays the coordinates. So far it works. (However it does not update the coordinates)

However whenever I touch outside the sub-view, into the main view the app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS message. From what I understand the main View cannot access the global variable if it's declared in another class ?

I've read many there stack overflows about this and I;ve tried it in the methods suggested but I keep getting this error.

Comment: Changing implementation of your logic avoiding global variable will take 5 minutes, don't use bad practices

Comment: "I wanted to try the same app but using global variables." - Don't. These delegate-protocol patterns may seem confusing the first time you use them, but it's there for a good reason: It's safer and makes the functional intent clear, and, especially as your app grows and grows, makes if far easier to maintain. If you have a working pattern and are looking for design feedback for improvements, consider posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Re your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, if you really need help with that, post the [simplest and smallest possible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that manifests that error and we can help you on that. Don't post all of your code, but rather make a new, extremely simple example that reproduces the problem you encounter.